# Role based menu in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, menu, roles

I am using Spring MVC for my web application. My views are JSP based. What is the best practice to show role based menus?

- Should I make a check on the JSP page for a role?
- Should I build the menu in a Java class and pass it to a JSP page to show up?
- Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make different role based menu pages and include them in you main content page at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Use a framework like `Spring Security` instead of implementing the complete security infrastructure on your own. Like all other Spring modules, you would simply configure the framework declaratively using XML (for defining roles etc.) and so it's quite flexible.

`Spring Security` comes with its own tag library that you would then use to secure your HTML elements. For example, to make a menu item available for Admin roles only just wrap it in an appropriate `<sec:authorize>` tag.

***References***:
[Spring Source](http://www.springsource.org/features/security) is a good place to begin with. Have a look at this video as well from their YouTube channel. [Getting Started with Spring Security 3.1](http://youtu.be/k32KqrckLEE)

Comment: @Downvoter, please do care to share your worthy alternative to Spring Security.